# Sinon Stub JavaScript Method Chain

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm looking to use sinon stub to test the method chain below:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize()
```

I found a related question that explains how to access one method down the chain, however this does not seem to give me access to any additional methods.

```
t.context.webdriver = sinon.stub(new WebDriver)
sinon.stub(t.context.webdriver, "manage", () => {
    return {
        window: sinon.stub().returns();
    };
})
```

which returns the error

```
Error: this._driver.manage(...).window(...).setSize is not a function
```

How to I stub multi-level method chains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your trying to to test, but the error is coming from the fact that the object your stub is returning doesn't have a `window()` function or a `setSize()`. Chains work because each part of the chain returns something with a method that matches the next call. So if you stuff something early in the chain, you need to makes sure what you return has those methods. Maybe that involves passing back the original return, or maybe you fake the whole chain.

Here's an example that at least won't throw:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')

// some fake object that maybe looks like what you have
let driver = {
manage(){ return this},
window() { return this},
setSize() {console.log("size set")}
}

// stubb manage and now you're resposible for the whole chain
sinon.stub(driver, "manage").callsFake(() => {
    console.log("called")
    return {
        window(){
            return { setSize: sinon.stub().returns() }
        }
    };
})
```

Of course, there are a lot of variations possible depending on what you're trying to test.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: That's a nice one. I am trying to use this and how can I test, say the window() method? Like if window method is getting called or some params are passed?

Comment: Sanish, it seems that you would need to make `driver.window()` a spy that you can test assertions on. It might be a little tricky to get it to return the correct `this`, but probably doable.